# Understanding the definition of inner product by Friedberg et. al.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

The following definition can be found in the book: Friedberg et. al., *Linear Algebra*, 5th Edition, page 327.

> **Definition.** Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$. An inner product on $V$
> is a function that assigns, to every ordered pair of vectors $x$ and $y$ in $V$, a scalar in $F$ , denoted $\langle x,y \rangle$, such that for all $x$, $y$, and $z$ in $V$ and all $c$ in $F$, the following hold:
>
> (a) $\langle x + z, y \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle + \langle z,y \rangle$
> (b) $\langle cx, y \rangle = c \langle x, y \rangle$
> (c) $\overline{\langle x, y \rangle } =  \langle y,x \rangle$, where the bar denotes complex conjugation
> (d) If $x \neq \overrightarrow{0}$, then $\langle x, x \rangle$ is a positive real number

In this definition, is there a bar missing in the RHS of c)?

If not, what is the idea behind this property c) which we require here  (as an inner product space axiom, if I may call it that way)? Is there any example or geometric meaning or anything else, so that one can build an intuition for c)?

Initially I thought yes (there's a bar missing in the RHS), but then I found the same equality in other sources/texts. So it seems the book definition is OK, it's not a typo.

**Note**
I've never studied inner product spaces before, the furthest I went
was dot/scalar product spaces, I don't think this axiom/property c)
is present there.

Comment: What is $F$? (c) only makes sense when $F=\Bbb C$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am not sure either. The chapter (6.1) starts with this definition and doesn't say clearly what F is. Of course throughout the book F denotes some field but... what field is meant here? I guess it can also be $\mathbb{R}$ or even $\mathbb{Q}$. Then c) is just equivalent to $\langle x,y \rangle=\langle y,x \rangle$. So I guess for my purposes it is OK to assume F is a number field which is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Actually the authors defined it. F is either R or C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complex conjugation in (c) leads to the definition
$$
\langle x, y \rangle = \sum_i x_i \bar {y_i}
$$
on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

That definition makes $\langle x, x \rangle \ge 0$, which is very useful for an inner product. When $n=1$ it is the square of the length of $x$ in the complex plane.

Comment: Hm... And what is F in the definition of the book? I guess it's a number field i.e. a sub-field of $\mathbb{C}$ and a super-field of $\mathbb{Q}$. Otherwise these bars would have no meaning, right?

Comment: @peter.petrov Yes.  I assume that somewhere earlier on the field was specified as either the reals or the complexes. It might be any field with a natural involution, but that's unlikely, as would an intermediate field.

Comment: OK, I see, thank you

Comment: Hello, sir Peter Petrov Can you just tell me If We Do products on the last equation of your image on both side what will happen?Actually I worked on a paper where I do a different proof a theorem but I think This idea can be adapted if we know how to define products over the ips.

Comment: @Math_Buddy Not sure I understand. I suggest you ask someone more knowledgeable. I am quite confused myself. So I am just trying to get some understanding of these basic concepts.

Comment: Just a small terminology quibble: "number field" means a finite-degree (hence, algebraic) extension of $\mathbb Q$. Not necessarily imbedded in $\mathbb C$. In fact, though number fields do admit several imbeddings into $\mathbb C$, rarely is there a well-defined "complex conjugation" on the number field that is independent of the choice of imbedding. This is probably not a significant point here, ...

Comment: @paulgarrett Yeah, sorry. I should have said a number field which is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. I mean OK... I don't want to imply that every number field is subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.